# not showing the title in django framework

Tags: python, django

I'm new to django framework and i'm using VS code

this is view.py file

```
posts = [
    {
        'author': 'CoreyMS',
        'title': 'Blog Post 1',
        'content': 'First post content',
        'date_posted': 'August 27, 2018'
    },
    {
        'author': 'Jane Doe',
        'title': 'Blog Post 2',
        'content': 'Second post content',
        'date_posted': 'August 28, 2018'
    }
]


def home(request):
    context = {
        'posts': posts
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/home.html', context)
```

and this my home.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
          {% if title %}
                <title>Django Blog - {{ title }}</title>
            {% else %}
                <title>Django Blog</title>
            {% endif %}
</head>
<body>
        {% for post in posts %}
        <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
        <p>{{ post.content }}</p>
        <p>{{ post.authorname }}</p>
        <p>{{ post.postdate }}</p>
        {% endfor %}

</body>
</html>
```

the body part works fine but the title doesn't work , i expect to see the title which is blog post one or blog post 2 
where is the problem ?
thank you

Comment: Your `context` dictionary should have an entry with the key `"title"`.

Comment: great ! i added {'title':'home'}. worked fine. thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
def home(request):
    context = {
        'posts': posts,
        'title': posts['title']
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/home.html', context)
```

But this kind of use is not good in practice. This is your homepage, not a post page. you don't need a specific post's title on the homepage.

I recommend use like that

1. Create Post model
2. Create url path for your view function (for post
   page)
3. Create html page for post_page view function

**in models.py**  and don't forget to migrate your model to the databse with `python manage.py makemigrations`  and `python manage.py migrate`

```
import django.db import models    
class Post(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
     slug = models.SlugField(
        max_length=250,
        unique_for_date='publish')
     author = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='blog_posts'
     )
     content = models.TextField()
     date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
     # What ever you want you can add
     def __str__(self):
         return self.title
```

**in urls.py**  looks like

```
urlpatterns = [
   # your paths what ever you have
   path('blog/<slug:post_slug>', views.post_page, name='post_page'),
]
```

**in views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Post
# and other imports 

def home(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    context = {
        'posts': posts
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/home.html', context)


def post_page(request, post_slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=post_slug)
    # and other operation you want 
    return render(request, 'blog/post_page.html', { 'post': post } )
```

then in your **post_page.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

                <title>{{ post.title }}</title>

</head>
<body>
<div>
        {{ post.content }}

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

after all I recommend make a base.html then extend your html pages from it

Answer (score 0):

> the body part works fine but the title doesn't work

I does - it prints an empty string for the 'title' var because there's no 'title' var in your context, and this is the expected behaviour

> i expect to see the title which is blog post one or blog post 2

Why would you expect such a thing ??? If you want your first post's title, use `{{ posts.0.title }}`. The template engine will NOT try to "guess" anything (hopefully), it just do what you ask for.

> where is the problem ?

Well, perhaps passing a value for `title` in your context might work ?

```
def home(request):
    context = {
        'posts': posts,
        'title': "This is my beautiful blog"
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/home.html', context)
```

Also and FWIW, you can make your template code a bit more DRY:

```
<title>Django Blog{% if title %}- {{ title }}{% endif %}</title>
```